# Match number and add before replace

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

Suppose I have in *text.txt*:

```
prop:"txt1"  prop:'txt4'  prop:"txt13"
```

And I want it to become (adding 9):

```
prop:"txt10"  prop:'txt13'  prop:"txt22"
```

In javascript, it would be:

```
var output = input.replace(/prop:(['"])txt(\d+)\1/g, function(match, quote, number){
    return "prop:" + quote + "txt" + (parseInt(number) + 9) + quote;
});
```

I'm trying to code the above code in C#:

```
string path = @"C:/text.txt";
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
File.WriteAllText(path, Regex.Replace(content, "prop:(['\"])txt(\\d+)\\1", ?????));
```

Visual Studio shows the third parameter should be `MatchEvaluator evaluator`. But I don't know how to declare/write/use it.

Any help is welcome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So in short you want to do **Arithmetic**  operation using regex ?

Comment: @noob. I need to change the number value, and the only idea that come my mind was using regex.. anyways, yes you can consider it arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Match evaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) and use `Int32.Parse` to parse the number as an int value that you can add 9 to:

```
Regex.Replace(content, @"prop:(['""])txt(\d+)\1", 
m => string.Format("prop:{0}txt{1}{0}",
     m.Groups[1].Value, 
    (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value) + 9).ToString()))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/48cNv2):

```
var content = "prop:\"txt1\"  prop:'txt4'  prop:\"txt13\"";
var r = Regex.Replace(content, @"prop:(['""])txt(\d+)\1", 
    m => string.Format("prop:{0}txt{1}{0}",
         m.Groups[1].Value, 
        (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value) + 9).ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(r); // => prop:"10"  prop:'13'  prop:"22"
```

Note that I am using a verbatim string literal so as to use a single backslash to escape special characters and define shorthand character classes (however, in a verbatim string literal a double quote must be doubled to denote a single literal double quote).

Answer (score 1):

[`MatchEvaluator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx). You need to write a function that takes a [`Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and returns the replacement value. One way to do this is shown below:

```
private static string AddEvaluator(Match match)
{
    int newValue = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) + 9;
    return String.Format("prop:{0}txt{1}{0}", match.Groups[1].Value, newValue)
}

public static void Main()
{
    string path = @"C:/text.txt";
    string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
    File.WriteAllText(path, Regex.Replace(content, "prop:(['\"])txt(\\d+)\\1", AddEvaluator));
}
```

Comment: I've marked the another as accepted because _fitted_ better... but thank you too +1... I think I got the idea now ;)